# Application not initialized

Tags: javascript, deployment, vuejs3, vite

I have a vue 3 app which builds and works fine locally. When I put the /dist directory inside the Nginx directory on the remote server the application is mounted (can see that in the logs) but nothing is displayed.

Am I missing any obvious config?

vite.config.ts

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from "url";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";
import vuetify from "vite-plugin-vuetify";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    vuetify({
      autoImport: true,
    }),
  ],
  base: '',
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": fileURLToPath(new URL("./src", import.meta.url)),
    },
  },
  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      scss: { charset: false },
      css: { charset: false },
    },
  },
  optimizeDeps: {
    exclude: ['vuetify'],
    entries: [
      './src/**/*.vue',
    ],
  },
});
```

main.js

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import { createPinia } from "pinia";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import vuetify from "./plugins/vuetify";
import "@/scss/style.scss";
import PerfectScrollbar from "vue3-perfect-scrollbar";
import VueApexCharts from "vue3-apexcharts";
import InstantSearch from "vue-instantsearch/vue3/es";
import VCalendar from "v-calendar";
import VueFeather from "vue-feather";
import mitt from 'mitt';
const emitter = mitt();

console.log("APP LOADED");

export const app = createApp(App).use(vuetify);

app.provide('viewer', 'hello world')
app.config.globalProperties.emitter = emitter;
window.$app = app;
window.$app.emitter = emitter;

app.component(VueFeather.name, VueFeather);
app.use(PerfectScrollbar);
app.use(InstantSearch);
app.use(createPinia());
app.use(VCalendar, {});
app.use(VueApexCharts);
app.use(router);
app.mount("#app");
```

Page is loaded. (see debug line) but nothing is displayed:

[image]

Page src

[image]

App.Vue

```
<template>
  <RouterView></RouterView>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { RouterView } from "vue-router";
import { onMounted} from "vue";

import { app } from './main.js';

//registed global events 
onMounted(() => {

  let script = document.createElement('script')
  script.setAttribute('src', "medview/STABLE/medview/MedView_en.js")
   document.head.appendChild(script)
  
  app.config.globalProperties.emitter.on("reload-profile", (data: any) => {
    console.log("reload profile");        
  });


});

</script>
```

Comment: `app = createApp(App).use(vuetify);` and then `app.use(vuetify)` looks wrong for a start. It's an SPA? did you configure nginx correctly?

Comment: yes nginx is configured. works if I put other files in that directory

Comment: Also changed the mount part-> no success

Comment: so, that's the full output of the console (which you've cutoff to the right for some reason)

Comment: `works if I put other files in that directory` - don't you have to configure it differently if you wish to serve a SPA? I always used to when I used it for SPA's

Comment: yes that is the whole output -> no errors

Comment: From what you've shown so far it looks like Vue loads properly but there's a condition (v-if!?) on your root element's only child which is `false` in production. Could also be related to route not matching, if your root element's only child is `<router-outlet>`. I can't be of more help without eyes on the actual failing build.

Comment: Please always [edit] clarifications into your question post instead of hiding them in the comments! Comments are for _soliciting_ clarifications- not for providing them.

Comment: Can you provide a minimum reproducible code?

Comment: The project works if I do a production build and place the files on a local webserver like apache.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Vue or nginx, so this might be a dumb question, but is there any difference if you open your website at `/` vs `/index.html`? How about a route that doesn't exist and should 404? Also, is it possible to share your nginx config?

Comment: Please provide your nginx configuration. It could be a trailing slash thats causing the router to miss.

Comment: Can you post App.vue code as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the files were hosted in a directory hdsconnect the sollution was to add this to vite.config path and inside routes path

router

```
 routes: [
    {
      path: "/hdsconnect/",
      redirect: "login",
      component: () => import("@/layouts/blank/BlankLayout.vue"),
      children: [
        {
```

vite config

```
  base: '/hdsconnect/',
```